# How can I use Session variable in an HttpHandler

Tags: .net, httphandler

Goal: I have a thumbnail as a byte array in memory. Once a user uploads their image, I want to display it in an httphandler before writing it to the database. I have used this code to successfully read it and display from a database. But now I want to display it from the session:

```
Public Sub ProcessRequest(ByVal context As HttpContext) _
    Implements IHttpHandler.ProcessRequest

    Dim oPhotoMgt As New PhotoMgt
    Dim intPhotoID As Int32 = context.Request.QueryString("id") 
    Dim oPhoto As New Photo
    oPhoto = oPhotoMgt.GetPhotoByID(intPhotoID)   

    context.Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg" 
    context.Response.BinaryWrite(oPhoto.Bytes.ToArray())
End Sub
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You should mark your class with the [IRequiresSessionState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.irequiressessionstate.aspx) interface (`System.Web.SessionState` namespace). It has no methods or properties, so you shouldn't have to change anything else about your code.

The signature would be:

```
Imports System.Web
Imports System.Web.SessionState

Public Class MyHandler
    Implements IHttpHandler, IRequiresSessionState

    Public Sub ProcessRequest(ByVal context As HttpContext) _
        Implements IHttpHandler.ProcessRequest

        context.Session("foo") = "bar"
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Thank you Thorarin. I implements IRequiresSessionState but it still can't see the Session variable. I am getting "Name 'Session' is not declared.

Comment: Updated the example to demonstrate the session use. +1 to Jack :)

Answer (score 1):

Thorarin was correct. I had to implement IRequiresSessionState. What I didn't realize was that I then had to refer to the variable as

```
context.Session("oUser")
```

instead of

```
Session("oUser")
```