# The instance of entity type cannot be tracked because another instance of this type with the same key is already being tracked

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I have a Service Object `Update`

```
public bool Update(object original, object modified)
{
    var originalClient = (Client)original;
    var modifiedClient = (Client)modified;
    _context.Clients.Update(originalClient); //<-- throws the error
    _context.SaveChanges();
    //Variance checking and logging of changes between the modified and original
}
```

This is where I am calling this method from:

```
public IActionResult Update(DetailViewModel vm)
{
    var originalClient = (Client)_service.GetAsNoTracking(vm.ClientId);
    var modifiedClient = (Client)_service.Fetch(vm.ClientId.ToString());
    // Changing the modifiedClient here
    _service.Update(originalClient, modifiedClient);
}
```

Here is the `GetAsNotTracking` method:

```
public Client GetAsNoTracking(long id)
{
    return GetClientQueryableObject(id).AsNoTracking().FirstOrDefault();
}
```

`Fetch` method:

```
public object Fetch(string id)
{
   long fetchId;
   long.TryParse(id, out fetchId);
   return GetClientQueryableObject(fetchId).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

`GetClientQueryableObject`:

```
private Microsoft.Data.Entity.Query.IIncludableQueryable<Client, ActivityType> GetClientQueryableObject(long searchId)
{
    return _context.Clients
        .Where(x => x.Id == searchId)
        .Include(x => x.Opportunities)
        .ThenInclude(x => x.BusinessUnit)
        .Include(x => x.Opportunities)
        .ThenInclude(x => x.Probability)
        .Include(x => x.Industry)
        .Include(x => x.Activities)
        .ThenInclude(x => x.User)
        .Include(x => x.Activities)
        .ThenInclude(x => x.ActivityType);
 }
```

Any ideas?

I have looked the following articles / discussions. To no avail:[ASP.NET GitHub Issue 3839](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/3839)

**UPDATE:**

Here are the changes to `GetAsNoTracking`:

```
public Client GetAsNoTracking(long id)
{
    return GetClientQueryableObjectAsNoTracking(id).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

`GetClientQueryableObjectAsNoTracking`:

```
private IQueryable<Client> GetClientQueryableObjectAsNoTracking(long searchId)
{
    return _context.Clients
        .Where(x => x.Id == searchId)
        .Include(x => x.Opportunities)
        .ThenInclude(x => x.BusinessUnit)
        .AsNoTracking()
        .Include(x => x.Opportunities)
        .ThenInclude(x => x.Probability)
        .AsNoTracking()
        .Include(x => x.Industry)
        .AsNoTracking()
        .Include(x => x.Activities)
        .ThenInclude(x => x.User)
        .AsNoTracking()
        .Include(x => x.Activities)
        .ThenInclude(x => x.ActivityType)
        .AsNoTracking();
}
```

Comment: I think where you're putting `AsNoTracking()` might be a bit late, as `_context.Clients` is already being tracked.  Try putting your `AsNoTracking()` directly on the `_context.Clients` call.  All of your `lnclude`s should probably be `AsNoTracking()` as well, unless you plan on tracking those.

Comment: @RobertHarvey trying it now. Will let you know.

Comment: Can I ask why you are getting an original and modified? Why can't you just get the original, make modifications, then call update? I don't see the point of getting modified?

Comment: @garethb I have to do an audit log. So I have a Variance Checker that checks on changes in the two objects and logs it to the database.

Comment: Oh, just saw the comment in the code, missed that :) @RobertHarvey answer should work

Comment: @RobertHarvey I tried your suggestion. I added the `AsNoTracking()` to the `_context` call. Not working. Shall I update the question with my changes?

Comment: I added the changes recommended.

Comment: What happens if you call GetAsNoTracking for both modified and original?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110206/discussion-between-rijnhardt-and-garethb).

Comment: @garethb it worked, thanks.

Comment: For the record: one `AsNoTracking()` call is enough, no matter where.

Comment: I have 3 questions: 1. Why do you include `Opportunities` and `Activities` twice? 2. What is the difference between `.Include` and `.ThenInclude`? 3. Isn't `.AsNoTracking()` at the end (or at the beginning) of the expression enough? Regarding 2. - shouldn't it be used in a way that only the first one is `.Include`, all the following ones are `.ThenInclude` (like it is with `.OrderBy` and `.ThenBy`) ?

Answer (score 139):

Without overriding EF track system, you can also Detach the 'local' entry and attach your updated entry before saving :

```
// 
var local = _context.Set<YourEntity>()
    .Local
    .FirstOrDefault(entry => entry.Id.Equals(entryId));

// check if local is not null 
if (local != null)
{
    // detach
    _context.Entry(local).State = EntityState.Detached;
}
// set Modified flag in your entry
_context.Entry(entryToUpdate).State = EntityState.Modified;

// save 
_context.SaveChanges();
```

**UPDATE:**
To avoid code redundancy, you can do an extension method :

```
public static void DetachLocal<T>(this DbContext context, T t, string entryId) 
    where T : class, IIdentifier 
{
    var local = context.Set<T>()
        .Local
        .FirstOrDefault(entry => entry.Id.Equals(entryId));
    if (!local.IsNull())
    {
        context.Entry(local).State = EntityState.Detached;
    }
    context.Entry(t).State = EntityState.Modified;
}
```

My `IIdentifier` interface has just an `Id` string property.

Whatever your Entity, you can use this method on your context :

```
_context.DetachLocal(tmodel, id);
_context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: I am trying to do this in a generic repository in which I don't have access to the entity's primary key (which could have any name and be of any type). Is there a way of finding the locally tracked entity in this scenario? Clearly EF can do it internally but I can't find a public API for it.

Comment: Caveat; this code needs LanguageExt package for `local.IsNull()` ... `<PackageReference Include="LanguageExt.Core" Version="4.2.1" />`. The function isn't built into EF Core.

Answer (score 53):

```
public async Task<Product> GetValue(int id)
{
    Product Products = await _context.Products
        .AsNoTracking().FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == id);
    return Products;
}
```

**AsNoTracking()**

**Important:** Using `AsNoTracking()` works like a charm in many contexts. However, unit tests will fail when using mocking or stubbing strategies with frameworks like `Moq`. Official explanation from MSDN:

> However, properly mocking `DbSet` query functionality is not possible, since queries are expressed via LINQ operators, which are static extension method calls over `IQueryable`. As a result, when some people talk about "mocking `DbSet`", what they really mean is that they create a `DbSet` backed by an in-memory collection, and then evaluate query operators against that collection in memory, just like a simple `IEnumerable`. Rather than a mock, this is actually a sort of fake, where the in-memory collection replaces the real database.

Avoid future issues when trying to unit test with a mocking strategy. There are other ways of unit testing like implementing the repository pattern, as mentioned in [the Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/testing/choosing-a-testing-strategy).

Comment: Worked for me...!

Comment: Worked like a charm.

Comment: AsNoTracking could bring a lot of issues when loading entity with many related entities.

Answer (score 52):

For me this just fixed the problem. Add this code before any update

```
_context.ChangeTracker.Clear()
```

From [Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.changetracking.changetracker.clear?view=efcore-5.0)

> Stops tracking all currently tracked entities.
>
> DbContext is designed to have a short lifetime where a new instance is
> created for each unit-of-work. This manner means all tracked entities
> are discarded when the context is disposed at the end of each
> unit-of-work. However, clearing all tracked entities using this method
> may be useful in situations where creating a new context instance is
> not practical.
>
> This method should always be preferred over detaching every tracked
> entity. Detaching entities is a slow process that may have side
> effects. This method is much more efficient at clearing all tracked
> entities from the context.
>
> Note that this method does not generate StateChanged events since
> entities are not individually detached.

**Update**

[Microsoft explanation of simple unit of work](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application)

**Update**

It is best to not call the `Update()` method. Just use the tracking feature when querying objects that needs to be modified then call `SaveChanges()` method which will update only the edited fields in an optimized way. That's how Tracking of EfCore works. Tracking is a good feature if it is used well.

If tracking is disabled in your project or for any other reason then use this method that I created. It is the optimized solution for updating object for EFCore. Call it instead of `Update()` Method of the `DbContext` and it will check if the object is tracked or not. If it tracked then it will do nothing. If object is not tracked then it will do the tracking work manually. Just call `SaveChanges()` method after and it will created the optimized SQL statement that will update only the fields that has been changed. This will also help you if you want to create an auditing feature to your app to track easily the changes of each row for all your data.

```
public void UpdateIfNoTracking(TEntity entityToUpdate) where TEntity : class
{
     var keys = GetPrimaryKeys(context, entityToUpdate);

     bool tracked = context.Entry(entityToUpdate).State != EntityState.Detached;

     if (tracked)
         return;

     if (keys != null)
     {
            
         var oldValues = context.Set<TEntity>().Find(keys);

            context.Entry(oldValues).CurrentValues.SetValues(entityToUpdate);
     }
     else
     {
         context.Set<TEntity>().Attach(entityToUpdate);
         context.Entry(entityToUpdate).State = EntityState.Modified;
     }
 }
```

I published the full solution library at [Github:Solid.DataAccess](https://github.com/sparrow58/Solid.DataAccess/tree/master) which applies the Unit Of Work and Repository Pattern in a good way. I use it in all my projects and it works like charm. Feel free to clone and contribute to making it better.

`GetPrimaryKeys()` Method is for getting all the primary keys values of the object dynamicly since I'm using Generic object. That helps a lot when using composite or multiple primary keys for an entity.

```
 private static object[] GetPrimaryKeys<T>(DbContext context, T value)
 {
     var keyNames = context.Model.FindEntityType(typeof(T)).FindPrimaryKey().Properties
               .Select(x => x.Name).ToArray();
     var result = new object[keyNames.Length];
     for (int i = 0; i < keyNames.Length; i++)
     {
         result[i] = typeof(T).GetProperty(keyNames[i])?.GetValue(value);
     }
     return result;
 }
```

Comment: Only avaliable on ef core 5.0 and above

Comment: this is what I needed since I am unit testing w/ an InMemory DB - so when adding things to then remove later I was getting the exception.  +1 for saving me a few hours..

Comment: Thanks man !!!!
Following a tutorial who is using EF InMemory, they don't use this sentence, so only the method UPDATE is not working in my RESTful environment.
I spent a whole day trying to figure out how to make it work, until I found your post!
Thank you !

Comment: GetPrimaryKeys method is missing in above code. pls explain the function GetPrimaryKeys()

Comment: @AbhishekB. I updated the answer with method and explanation. If you want the full solution please go to the link above Solid.DataAccess

Comment: Thanks @sabsab to update with explanation.

Answer (score 20):

In my case, the table's id column was not set as an Identity column.

Comment: you saved me :) I had my key set, but wrongly (Id and Level instead of only Id) and therefore I got this error exception.

Answer (score 11):

It sounds as you really just want to track the changes made to the model, not to actually keep an untracked model in memory. May I suggest an alternative approach which will remove the problem entirely?

EF will automatically track changes for you. How about making use of that built in logic?

Override `SaveChanges()` in your `DbContext`.

```
    public override int SaveChanges()
    {
        foreach (var entry in ChangeTracker.Entries<Client>())
        {
            if (entry.State == EntityState.Modified)
            {
                // Get the changed values.
                var modifiedProps = ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntry(entry.EntityKey).GetModifiedProperties();
                var currentValues = ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntry(entry.EntityKey).CurrentValues;
                foreach (var propName in modifiedProps)
                {
                    var newValue = currentValues[propName];
                    //log changes
                }
            }
        }

        return base.SaveChanges();
    }
```

Good examples can be found here:

[Entity Framework 6: audit/track changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26355486/entity-framework-6-audit-track-changes)

[Implementing Audit Log / Change History with MVC & Entity Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6867459/implementing-audit-log-change-history-with-mvc-entity-framework)

**EDIT:**
`Client` can easily be changed to an interface. Let's say `ITrackableEntity`. This way you can centralize the logic and automatically log all changes to all entities that implement a specific interface. The interface itself doesn't have any specific properties.

```
    public override int SaveChanges()
    {
        foreach (var entry in ChangeTracker.Entries<ITrackableClient>())
        {
            if (entry.State == EntityState.Modified)
            {
                // Same code as example above.
            }
        }

        return base.SaveChanges();
    }
```

Also, take a look at [eranga](https://stackoverflow.com/users/60108/eranga)'s great suggestion to subscribe instead of actually overriding SaveChanges().

Comment: I have actually looked at these examples; some issues that I got was that it needed to be enabled on certain tables. The use cases used there was a broad implementation. Thanks for the feedback. Really appreciate it.

Comment: this could get somewhere, thanks for the input. just one query, though -- how do I get the authorized user? I am needing it for the audit log. Can I use the `User.GetUserId()`?

Comment: That would depend on your application and how you authenticate the user. Is it WPF, ASP, MVC etc. I usually abstract it to a manager or util that can retrieve the current user. User.GetUserId() sounds like something that is available in the Controller, which is short for HttpContext.User. So you need HttpContext. Here's someting that will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1918283/how-to-access-httpcontext-outside-of-controllers-in-asp-net-mvc, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5898170/how-to-get-user-identity-working-outside-controller

Comment: HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.GetUserId();

Answer (score 11):

I had the same issue (EF Core) while setting up xUnit tests.
What 'fixed' it for me in testing was looping through the change tracker entities after setting up the seed data.

- at the bottom of the SeedAppDbContext() method.

***I set up a Test Mock Context:***

```
/// <summary>
/// Get an In memory version of the app db context with some seeded data
/// </summary>
public static AppDbContext GetAppDbContext(string dbName)
{
    //set up the options to use for this dbcontext
    var options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<AppDbContext>()
        .UseInMemoryDatabase(databaseName: dbName)
        //.UseQueryTrackingBehavior(QueryTrackingBehavior.NoTracking)
        .Options;

    var dbContext = new AppDbContext(options);
    dbContext.SeedAppDbContext();
    return dbContext;
}
```

***Extension method to add some seed data***:

- and detach entities in `foreach` loop at bottom of method.

```
    public static void SeedAppDbContext(this AppDbContext appDbContext)
    {
       // add companies
       var c1 = new Company() { Id = 1, CompanyName = "Fake Company One", ContactPersonName = "Contact one", eMail = "one@caomp1.com", Phone = "0123456789", AdminUserId = "" };
       c1.Address = new Address() { Id = 1, AddressL1 = "Field Farm", AddressL2 = "Some Lane", City = "some city", PostalCode = "AB12 3CD" };
       appDbContext.CompanyRecords.Add(c1);
                        
       var nc1 = new Company() { Id = 2, CompanyName = "Test Company 2", ContactPersonName = "Contact two", eMail = "two@comp2.com", Phone = "0123456789", Address = new Address() { }, AdminUserId = "" };
       nc1.Address = new Address() { Id = 2, AddressL1 = "The Barn", AddressL2 = "Some Lane", City = "some city", PostalCode = "AB12 3CD" };
       appDbContext.CompanyRecords.Add(nc1);

       //....and so on....
            
       //last call to commit everything to the memory db
       appDbContext.SaveChanges();

       //and then to detach everything 
       foreach (var entity in appDbContext.ChangeTracker.Entries())
       {
           entity.State = EntityState.Detached;
       }
    }
```

***The controller put method***

The *`.ConvertTo<>()`* Method is an extension method from [ServiceStack](https://servicestack.net/)

```
 [HttpPut]
public async Task<IActionResult> PutUpdateCompany(CompanyFullDto company)
{
    if (0 == company.Id)
        return BadRequest();
    try
    {
        Company editEntity = company.ConvertTo<Company>();
        
        //Prior to detaching an error thrown on line below (another instance with id)
        var trackedEntity = _appDbContext.CompanyRecords.Update(editEntity);
        

        await _appDbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
    catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException dbError)
    {
        if (!CompanyExists(company.Id))
            return NotFound();
        else
            return BadRequest(dbError);
    }
    catch (Exception Error)
    {
        return BadRequest(Error);
    }
    return Ok();
}
```

***and the test:***

```
    [Fact]
    public async Task PassWhenEditingCompany()
    {
        var _appDbContext = AppDbContextMocker.GetAppDbContext(nameof(CompaniesController));
        var _controller = new CompaniesController(null, _appDbContext);

        //Arrange
        const string companyName = "Fake Company One";
        const string contactPerson = "Contact one";

        const string newCompanyName = "New Fake Company One";
        const string newContactPersonName = "New Contact Person";

        //Act
        var getResult = _controller.GetCompanyById(1);
        var getEntity = (getResult.Result.Result as OkObjectResult).Value;
        var entityDto = getEntity as CompanyFullDto;


        //Assert
        Assert.Equal(companyName, entityDto.CompanyName);
        Assert.Equal(contactPerson, entityDto.ContactPersonName);
        Assert.Equal(1, entityDto.Id);

        //Arrange
        Company entity = entityDto.ConvertTo<Company>();
        entity.CompanyName = newCompanyName;
        entity.ContactPersonName = newContactPersonName;
        CompanyFullDto entityDtoUpd = entity.ConvertTo<CompanyFullDto>();

        //Act
        var result = await _controller.PutUpdateCompany(entityDtoUpd) as StatusCodeResult;

        //Assert           
        Assert.True(result.StatusCode == 200);

        //Act
        getResult = _controller.GetCompanyById(1);
        getEntity = (getResult.Result.Result as OkObjectResult).Value;
        
        entityDto = getEntity as CompanyFullDto;
        
        //Assert
        Assert.Equal(1, entityDto.Id); // didn't add a new record
        Assert.Equal(newCompanyName, entityDto.CompanyName); //updated the name
        Assert.Equal(newContactPersonName, entityDto.ContactPersonName); //updated the contact

//make sure to dispose of the _appDbContext otherwise running the full test will fail.
_appDbContext.Dispose();
    }
```

Answer (score 6):

For me, I was experiencing this issue while also using AutoMapper and .NET 6.  To resolve it, I changed the code from:

```
DbItem? result = await _dbContext.DbItems.FirstOrDefaultAsync(t => t.Id == id);
if (result == null)
{
    return null;
}
DbItem mappedItem = _mapper.Map<DbItem>(dto);  //problematic line
var updatedItem = _dbContext.DbItems.Update(mappedItem);
```

To:

```
DbItem? result = await _dbContext.DbItems.FirstOrDefaultAsync(t => t.Id == id);
if (result == null)
{
    return null;
}
_mapper.Map(dto, result);  //the fix
var updatedItem = _dbContext.DbItems.Update(result);
```

The problematic line created a NEW DbItem with the same key value(s), leading to the issue.  The fix line maps the fields from the DTO to the original DbItem.

Comment: Bingo! That was my issue.

Comment: And how would you deal with nested entities? For example {name: "item 1", SubItems: [{name: "SubItem1"}]}. Even if I do `_mapper. Map(dto, result);` the sub-items array will be replaced with objects with different references which is equal to `_mapper.Map<DbSubItem>(x);`

Answer (score 5):

Had this problem too.. Solved it by untracking the old entity first before saving.

```
 public async Task<int> Update<T>(T entity) where T : BaseEntity
{
    entity.UpdatedAt = DateTime.UtcNow;

    // Untrack previous entity version
    var trackedEntity = this.context.Set<T>()
        .SingleOrDefaultAsync(e => e.Id == entity.Id);
    this.context.Entry<T>(await trackedEntity).State = EntityState.Detached;

    // Track new version
    this.context.Set<T>().Attach(entity);
    this.context.Entry<T>(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;

    await this.context.SaveChangesAsync();

    return entity.Id;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You could just set the entity to detatched after saving, like this:

```
public async Task<T> Update(int id, T entity)
    {
        entity.Id = id;
        _ctx.Set<T>().Update(entity);
        await _ctx.SaveChangesAsync();
        _ctx.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Detached; //detach saved entity
        return entity;
    }
```

Comment: Worked for me. I'm using .Net Core 3.0 in this application.
I also had to set this in the constructor for my repository in order to make it work: DbContext.ChangeTracker.QueryTrackingBehavior = QueryTrackingBehavior.NoTracking;

Comment: I'm getting an exception near the saveChanges method, ie.., before the line where I add Detached, any clue how to fix it ?

Comment: what kind of exception?

Answer (score 3):

In EF core - also make sure that you dont set both the foreign key and the foreign key navigation property. I got this error when I set both the key and the property.

e.g.

```
        new VerificationAccount()
        {
            Account = konto_1630,
            VerificationRowType = VerificationRowType.Template,
            // REMOVED THE LINE BELOW AND THE ERROR WENT AWAY
            //VerificationAccount = verificationAccounts.First(x => x.Account == konto_1630),
            VerificationId = verificationId
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Just as the error message says, there're two entities being tracked.
If you're doing an update operation:

1. do a Get and get the entity
2. update that entity by setting the properties of that entity. Do not do a new on the entity in question.  This creates two entities.

Comment: Thanks! That was the correct answer in my case

Answer (score 0):

I got this error from my background service. I solved which creating a new scope.

```
                using (var scope = serviceProvider.CreateScope())
                {
                      // Process
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

This error message can happen if you have duplicate entries/entities and run SaveChanges().

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: This is a true comment I inserted unique values and error disappeared.

Comment: Glad it helped someone @AtahanCeylan :)

Answer (score 0):

If you have setted two or more tables with 'Id' or columns name with the same column name, the easiest way is to change OnModelCreating method in the context class.

In this case I have to change the 'Id' to 'AbandonedCartId' and tell to entity that object has column name 'Id'

```
entity.Property(e => e.AbandonedCartId).HasColumnName("Id");
```

Example

```
public partial class AbandonedCart
    {
        public int AbandonedCartId { get; set; }
        public double? CheckoutId { get; set; }
        public int? AppId { get; set; }
        public double? CustomerId { get; set; }
        
    }
```

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
 {
            modelBuilder.Entity<AbandonedCart>(entity =>
            {
                entity.Property(e => e.AbandonedCartId).HasColumnName("Id");
                entity.Property(e => e.CreatedAt).HasColumnType("datetime");

                entity.HasOne(d => d.App)
                    .WithMany(p => p.AbandonedCart)
                    .HasForeignKey(d => d.AppId)
                    .HasConstraintName("FK_AbandonedCart_Apps");
            });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was a mistake of saving changes twice for a unit of work. I was using saveChangesAsync() so it did not occurr immediatly, but later.

Answer (score -1):

Arhhh this got me and I spent a lot of time troubleshooting it. The problem was my tests were being executed in Parellel (the default with XUnit).

To make my test run sequentially I decorated each class with this attribute:

```
[Collection("Sequential")]
```

**This is how I worked it out:** [Execute unit tests serially (rather than in parallel)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1408175/execute-unit-tests-serially-rather-than-in-parallel/34876963)

---

I mock up my EF In Memory context with GenFu:

```
private void CreateTestData(TheContext dbContext)
{
    GenFu.GenFu.Configure<Employee>()
       .Fill(q => q.EmployeeId, 3);
    var employee = GenFu.GenFu.ListOf<Employee>(1);

    var id = 1;
    GenFu.GenFu.Configure<Team>()
        .Fill(p => p.TeamId, () => id++).Fill(q => q.CreatedById, 3).Fill(q => q.ModifiedById, 3);
    var Teams = GenFu.GenFu.ListOf<Team>(20);
    dbContext.Team.AddRange(Teams);

    dbContext.SaveChanges();
}
```

When Creating Test Data, from what I can deduct, it was alive in two scopes (once in the Employee's Tests while the Team tests were running):

```
public void Team_Index_should_return_valid_model()
{
    using (var context = new TheContext(CreateNewContextOptions()))
    {
        //Arrange
        CreateTestData(context);
        var controller = new TeamController(context);

        //Act
        var actionResult = controller.Index();

        //Assert
        Assert.NotNull(actionResult);
        Assert.True(actionResult.Result is ViewResult);
        var model = ModelFromActionResult<List<Team>>((ActionResult)actionResult.Result);
        Assert.Equal(20, model.Count);
    }
}
```

Wrapping both Test Classes with this sequential collection attribute has cleared the apparent conflict.

```
[Collection("Sequential")]
```

Additional references:

https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/7340
[EF Core 2.1 In memory DB not updating records](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50530949/ef-core-2-1-in-memory-db-not-updating-records)
http://www.jerriepelser.com/blog/unit-testing-aspnet5-entityframework7-inmemory-database/
http://gunnarpeipman.com/2017/04/aspnet-core-ef-inmemory/
https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/12459
[Preventing tracking issues when using EF Core SqlLite in Unit Tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42138960/preventing-tracking-issues-when-using-ef-core-sqllite-in-unit-tests)

Answer (score -1):

I faced the same problem but the issue was very silly, By mistake I have given wrong relationship I have given relationship between 2 Ids.

Comment: But sometimes you need a relationship between two IDs, like when you want a UNIQUE index

Answer (score -1):

```
public static void DetachEntity<T>(this DbContext dbContext, T entity, string propertyName) where T: class, new()
{
   try
   {
      var dbEntity = dbContext.Find<T>(entity.GetProperty(propertyName));
      if (dbEntity != null)
          dbContext.Entry(dbEntity).State = EntityState.Detached;
      dbContext.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
   }
   catch (Exception)
   {
        throw;
   }
}


 public static object GetProperty<T>(this T entity, string propertyName) where T : class, new()
 {
    try
    {
        Type type = entity.GetType();
        PropertyInfo propertyInfo = type.GetProperty(propertyName);
        object value = propertyInfo.GetValue(entity);
        return value;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
         throw;
    }
 }
```

I made this 2 extension methods, this is working really well.

Answer (score -1):

Cant update the DB row. I was facing the same error. Now working with following code:

```
_context.Entry(_SendGridSetting).CurrentValues.SetValues(vm);
await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

Answer (score -1):

I had this problem myself. Entity Framework keeps track of every object you insert into the database. So when you insert a duplicate record of the same object with a few fields being changed, EF will throw this error. I got around it by deep cloning the object I'm trying to re-insert, and it went through.

```
    public static T DeepClone<T>(this T a)
    {
        using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            formatter.Serialize(stream, a);
            stream.Position = 0;
            return (T)formatter.Deserialize(stream);
        }
    }
```

then:

```
var cloned = objectYouAreTryingToReinsert.deepClone();
context.objects.add(cloned);
await context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

Comment: This doesn't solve the issue. If an object with the same key is attached to the context you can't attach *any* other object (of the same class) with the same key, cloned or not.

Answer (score -1):

I have had the same problem before and solved it by replacing `AddDbContext` with the `AddDbContextFactory` to the services container.

**This is how I solved the issue:**

Instead of registering `AddDbContext`, I registered `AddDbContextFactory` instead, like this:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
services.AddDbContextFactory<YourApplicationDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("YourDatabaseConnectionString")));
}
```

**IMPORTANT REMINDER:**

**Do not** register `AddDbContext` and `AddDbContextFactory` together because you will get a `System.AggregateException: 'Some services are not able to be constructed...'` `exception`. Use `AddDbContextFactory` instead.

Your `ApplicationDbContext` class must expose a public constructor with a `DbContextOptions<YourApplicationDbContext>` parameter like this:

```
public class YourApplicationDbContext : DbContext
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<YourApplicationDbContext> options): base(options){}
}
```

The `DbContextFactory` factory can then be used through constructor injection like this:

```
private readonly IDbContextFactory<YourApplicationDbContext> dbContextFactory;

public YourConstructor(IDbContextFactory<YourApplicationDbContext> dbContextFactory)
{
    dbContextFactory = dbContextFactory;
}
```

or

```
public YourController(IDbContextFactory<YourApplicationDbContext> dbContextFactory)
{
    dbContextFactory = dbContextFactory;
}
```

The injected factory can then be used to construct `DbContext` instances in the service code like this:

```
   using (var context = dbContextFactory.CreateDbContext())
        {
            // your database CRUD code comes in here... for example:
            context.DatabaseTable.Update(suppliedModel);
            await context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
```

**When you may consider this option:**
*Registering a factory instead of registering the context type directly allows you easy creation of new DbContext instances. It is also recommended for Blazor applications.*

I hope this helps someone facing this issue. Cheers!

Answer (score -1):

Extension method to detach entity for any key type.

```
public static void Detach<TEntry, TId>(this DbContext context, Func<TEntry, TId> idReader, TId id) 
    where TEntry : class
    where TId : IEquatable<TId>
{
    var local = context.Set<TEntry>()
        .Local
        .FirstOrDefault(entry => idReader(entry).Equals(id));
    if (local != null)
    {
        context.Entry(local).State = EntityState.Detached;
    }
}
```

Usage for Guid key:

```
dbContext.Detach<EntryType, Guid>(e => e.Id, myEntity.Id);
dbContext.Attach(myEntity);
```

Answer (score -1):

For me, I have the same entity in navigation property.

e.g.

```
class Entity1
{
    public ICollection<Entity2> Entities2 { get; set; } // <-- problem
}

class Entity2
{
    public Entity1 Ent { get; set; } // <-- problem
}
```

Solution

```
Entity1 e = ...
e.Entities2 = null;
db.SaveChanges();
```

Answer (score -2):

If your data has changed every once,you will notice dont tracing the table.for example some table update id ([key]) using tigger.If you tracing ,you will get same id and get the issue.

Comment: Interessing can you explain better?