# net core 2.0 Entity Framework error on Update .The instance of entity type cannot be tracked

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core-2.0

I am doing an net `core 2.0 Application`, with `Entity Framework`.

I want to `update` a record table, where I first, have to do a Select to get the current i want to update.

I am having this error..

```html
"The instance of entity type 'MarketOrder' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'MarketOrderID'} is already being tracked. 
When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached. Consider using 'DbContextOptionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging' to see the conflicting key values."
```

I looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36856073/the-instance-of-entity-type-cannot-be-tracked-because-another-instance-of-this-t) answer, but it did not help.

Here is my code.

```html
MarketOrder marketOrder = _context.MarketOrders.FirstOrDefault(t => t.MarketOrderID == id);

 marketOrder.Status = status;
 marketOrder.LastUpdate = DateTime.Now;

//     _context.Entry(marketOrder).State = EntityState.Detached;

  _context.MarketOrders.Attach(marketOrder);
  _context.Entry(marketOrder).Property(x => x.Status).IsModified = true;
  _context.Entry(marketOrder).Property(x => x.LastUpdate).IsModified = true;
  _context.SaveChanges();
```

I have an error in line

```
_context.MarketOrders.Attach(marketOrder);
```

The field `MarketOrderID`  is the Primary Key.

As far as I search and test it. I found that the problem is HOW i do the select...

if I do the select in this way

```
 MarketOrder marketOrder = _context.MarketOrders.FirstOrDefault(t => t.MarketOrderID == id);
```

Got that error...

But If I do it this way.

```
MarketOrder marketOrder = _context.MarketOrders.Find(id);
```

it Works fine.

In same cases I have to retrieve the record using a more complex Select. so it will be nice to find the way it can work using

```
MarketOrder marketOrder = _context.MarketOrders.FirstOrDefault(t => t.MarketOrderID == id);
```

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: You don't need to attach again. As the error says it is already being tracked

Comment: Yes... Thanks ozz.. You made my day

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make sure your context is aware that your entity has been modified, the line for that is rather :

```
_context.Entry(marketOrder).State = EntityState.Modified;
```

But you don't even need that ! Since you retrieve your entity directly from this function :

```
_context.MarketOrders.FirstOrDefault(t => t.MarketOrderID == id);
```

Entity framework is already "tracking" the object. It comes DIRECTLY form your context. No need to attach anything or specify any state.