# EF Core 2.1 In memory DB not updating records

Tags: entity-framework-core

I'm using the in memory database provider for integration tests however I don't seem to be able to update a record. I've run the same code against a real SQL database and everything gets updated fine. Here is my test fixture code.

**Test Fixture:**

```
public class TestFixture<TStartup> : IDisposable
{
    private readonly TestServer _testServer;
    public HttpClient TestClient { get; }
    public IDatabaseService DbContext { get { return _testServer.Host.Services.GetService<DatabaseService>(); } }

    public TestFixture() : this(Path.Combine("src")) { }

protected TestFixture(string relativeTargetProjectPatentDir)
{
    Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT", "Testing");

    var builder = new WebHostBuilder()
        .ConfigureServices(services =>
        {
            services.AddDbContext<DatabaseService>(options =>
                options.UseInMemoryDatabase("TestDB")
                .EnableSensitiveDataLogging());
        })
        .UseEnvironment("Testing")
        .UseStartup<Startup>();

    _testServer = new TestServer(builder)
    {
        BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:5010")
    };

    TestClient = _testServer.CreateClient();
    TestClient.BaseAddress = _testServer.BaseAddress;
}

    public void Dispose()
    {
        TestClient.Dispose();
        _testServer.Dispose();
    }
}
```

I've spent most of the day googling this and not come across any other people talking about it so I'm assuming its probably my issue rather than a EF bug. I'm sure someone would have noticed a DB that you can't update.

Comment: This related question can also help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54264787/unit-testing-with-ef-core-and-in-memory-database

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turned out that changing the lifetime of my DbContext in my test fixture to singleton solved my issue.

Comment: I used the same strategy but I did it using an XUnit attribute (to make my tests run sequentially): https://stackoverflow.com/a/55700172/495455

Comment: Thanks for the answer! This was really causing me a lot of confusion. I added to this post the change I made to get this working based on your answer.

Comment: but DbContext is not thread safe - how did that solve the problem?

Answer (score 7):

Updating works with Singleton but I have CQRS architecture and to check if the entry was updated in e2e test I have to reload entry

```
Context.Entry(entity).Reload();
```

I hope that this can help someone

Comment: That did help me indeed but I'm curious why is that needed in some cases while in other cases it seems to work just fine?

Comment: I would give you +2 if I could.  +1 for helping me out and +1 for mentioning the CQRS pattern which I am using, but not quite correctly.

Comment: @SaherAhwal If you could share the cases then maybe I could respond

Answer (score 1):

Well it can be that `DbContext` is used in wrong way. I had the same problem. I used the `DbContext` in same way as you. I simply returned the instance by `.Host.Services.GetService<TContext>`. The problem with this approach is that `DbContext` will never release tracked entities so either you set entity `State` as `EntityState.Detached` and you force `DbContext` to reload it, or you will use scopes.

```cs
using (var scope = _testServer.Host.Services.GetRequiredService<IServiceScopeFactory>().CreateScope())
{
  var dbContext = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<DatabaseService>();
  //make any operations on dbContext only in scope
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding to Chris's answer. Here is an example of what I had vs. what fixed the issue:

```cs
services.AddDbContext<TestDbContext>(options => {
 options.UseInMemoryDatabase("TestDb");
});
```

to

```cs
var options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<TestDbContext>()
                        .UseInMemoryDatabase(databaseName: "TestDb")
                        .Options;
services.AddSingleton(x => new TestDbContext(options));
```

Answer (score 1):

Using AsNoTracking behavior may additionally work below,

```
services.AddDbContext<TestDbContext>(
            a => a.UseInMemoryDatabase(databaseName: "TestDb").UseQueryTrackingBehavior(QueryTrackingBehavior.NoTracking),
            ServiceLifetime.Singleton)
```

Also, how are you updating record? This seems to track in EFCore InMemory,

```
_dbContext.Entry(modifyItem).State = EntityState.Modified;
```

However, this doesn't seem to work as much.

```
_dbContext.Entry(existingItem).CurrentValues.SetValues(modifyItem);
```