# Moq testing Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, moq

I am newbie to both `Entity Framework` and `Moq testing`.

Below is my `EF code`:

```
public class Repository<TEntity> : IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{

    protected readonly DbContext Context;
    public Repository(DbContext context)
    {
        Context = context;
    }

    public TEntity Get(int id)
    {
      
        return Context.Set<TEntity>().Find(id);
    }

    public IEnumerable<TEntity> GetAll()
    {
       
        return Context.Set<TEntity>().ToList();
    }

    public void Add(TEntity entity)
    {
        Context.Set<TEntity>().Add(entity);
    }

    public void Remove(TEntity entity)
    {
        Context.Set<TEntity>().Remove(entity);
    }

}


public interface IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{

    TEntity Get(int id);
    IEnumerable<TEntity> GetAll();


    void Add(TEntity entity);

    void Remove(TEntity entity);

}


public interface IUnitOfWork : IDisposable
{

    int Complete();
}


public class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
{


    private readonly EF_SalesOrdersDBContext _context;

    public CustomersRepository customersRepository { get; set; }

    public UnitOfWork(EF_SalesOrdersDBContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
        customersRepository = new CustomersRepository(_context);
    }



    public int Complete()
    {
        return _context.SaveChanges();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _context.Dispose();
    }
}

public class CustomersRepository : Repository<Customer>
{
    public CustomersRepository(EF_SalesOrdersDBContext context)
        :base(context)
    {
            
    }



}
```

Code below in `program.cs` which works.

```
   UnitOfWork unitOfWork = new UnitOfWork(new EF_SalesOrdersDBContext());
        unitOfWork.customersRepository.Add(new Customer { CompanyName = "test2", FirstName = "John", LastName = "Barnes", AddressLine1 = "11 lfc", City = "Liverpool", County = "LFC", Phone = "444" });         
        unitOfWork.Complete();
```

I would like test using `Moq`.

This is what I have tried:

```
 [TestClass]
public class UnitTest1
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
  
        var mockSet = new Mock<DbSet<Customer>>();

        var mockContext = new Mock<EF_SalesOrdersDBContext>();
        mockContext.Setup(m => m.Customers).Returns(mockSet.Object);


        var service = new CustomersRepository(mockContext.Object);

   

        service.Add(new Customer { CompanyName = "test2", FirstName = "John", LastName = "Barnes", AddressLine1 = "11 lfc", City = "Liverpool", County = "LFC", Phone = "444" });

        mockSet.Verify(m => m.Add(It.IsAny<Customer>()), Times.Once());
        mockContext.Verify(m => m.SaveChanges(), Times.Once());


    }

}
```

I get the error:

> Message:
> Test method UnitTestProject1.UnitTest1.TestMethod1 threw exception:
> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.   Stack Trace:
> Repository`1.Add(TEntity entity) line 34
> UnitTest1.TestMethod1() line 26

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A key reason for implementing a repository pattern with Entity Framework is to enable unit testing. The Repository becomes the abstraction point for the unit tests. Basically think of it this way:

- You trust that EF is written and tested correctly to guarantee you'll get what you're supposed to get.
- The repository's purpose is solely to serve as a relay, containing no high-level business logic.
- Any low-level rules that a repository may enforce that are dependent on Data State will be covered by integration tests. These tests would be run using either a known-state snapshot database or in-memory database.

So where your main business logic should be residing in your Services / Controllers, that is where your unit tests would be targeting. The Mocks are made for your Repositories, not EF DbContexts/DbSets.

So for example, given your structure I would have a Mock of the UnitOfWork which asserts whether any `Complete()` call is made (or not), then mock out the Repository for expected methods to return a known state.

Comment: The repository pattern is a hot topic. For me, it's a redundant layer as the entity framework context itself is the repository. Then you build your service classes on top of the db context factory that produces the necessary db contexts. But this is a matter of opinion, I have seen people argue well in both directions.

Comment: That it is. :) IMO it can be used for the right reasons, and it can be used for the wrong ones. It can make unit testing a lot simpler as it is easier to mock out a repository than something like a DbContext. Though if your team doesn't use/value unit tests, it has little value. Using repositories to try and hide EF behind a Facade is a big anti-pattern in my book. It either adds a *lot* of complexity, or cripples capability that EF could provide, or both. Generic repositories are another code smell I watch out for. (cripples capabilities)

Comment: Well said sir :)

Comment: The db context is the unit of work, and the sets are the repositories. I personally use repositories as they give me a level of abstraction that is useful, for implementing caching for example.

Answer (score 2):

Mocking db context is a bad idea - you can simply use an in memory context and avoid mocking everything. It will work just like the real database.

See these suggestions from Microsoft: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/testing/

This question has some answers that show how to make the in memory context: [Unit testing with EF Core and in memory database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54264787/unit-testing-with-ef-core-and-in-memory-database)

Comment: I think In Memory context does not support if use Sprocs for CRUD operations.

Comment: Certainly, you would need to mock those sprocs and abstract them behind some sort of service class. Using entity framework only wherever possible will make your testing life much easier, but there are the edge cases where a heavily optimized or ever changing sproc is warranted.

Comment: But I would recommend against sprocs for CRUD operations unless you have some sort of performance bottleneck.