# Unable to cast object of type 'System.Linq.Expressions.ConstantExpression' to type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryRootExpression'

Tags: c#, linq, unit-testing, asp.net-core, xunit

This is the function i am trying to write unit test for. On of the methods happens to use FromSqlRaw() to fetch the data from SQL Server via a stored procedure.

```
public async Task<IQueryable<LoadDetail>> GlobalSearchMobileByLocation(IQueryable<LoadDetail> loadDetails, List<LocationCoordinates> origin, List<LocationCoordinates> destination, int originRadius, int destinationRadius)
        {
            // Getting Cities within Radius
            Stopwatch getCitiesStopWatch = new Stopwatch();
            getCitiesStopWatch.Start();
            var rawsql = new StringBuilder();
            rawsql.Append(Constant.SqlBaseQueryLoadDetail);

            if (origin != null && originRadius != 0)
            {
                rawsql.Append(" ( ");
                foreach (var locationCoordinates in origin)
                {
                    rawsql.Append(BuildSearchMobileQuery(locationCoordinates, originRadius, Constant.OriginLatitudeField, Constant.OriginLongitudeField));
                }

                rawsql = new StringBuilder(rawsql.ToString().Substring(0, rawsql.ToString().LastIndexOf("or") - 1));
                rawsql.Append(") and ");
            }

            if (destination != null && destinationRadius != 0)
            {
                rawsql.Append(" ( ");
                foreach (var locationCoordinates in destination)
                {
                    rawsql.Append(BuildSearchMobileQuery(locationCoordinates, destinationRadius, Constant.DestinationLatitudeField, Constant.DestinationLongitudeField));
                }

                rawsql = new StringBuilder(rawsql.ToString().Substring(0, rawsql.ToString().LastIndexOf("or") - 1));
                rawsql.Append(") and ");
            }

            rawsql.Append(Constant.TrueStatementSql);
            var query = rawsql.ToString();
            try
            {
                loadDetails = _readContext.LoadDetails.FromSqlRaw(rawsql.ToString()).AsNoTracking().AsQueryable();
            }
            catch (Exception ex )
            {

                throw;
            }

            getCitiesStopWatch.Stop();
            _logger.LogInformation("Time taken to get cities based on radius(ms) : " + getCitiesStopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString());

            return await Task.FromResult(loadDetails);
        }
```

I wrote this x unit test case for the function but it is throwing error.

```
public void Should_return_LoadWithinTheDHRadius_OriginIsPassedOnly()
        {
            // Arrange
            var fixture = new Fixture();
            var loadDetail = Enumerable.Empty<LoadDetail>().AsQueryable();
            var loadDetailList = fixture.Create<LoadDetail>();
            loadDetailList.PickupDateTime = DateTime.Now.Date;
            loadDetailList.DeliveryDateTime = DateTime.Now.Date;
            loadDetailList.OriginZipCode = Constant.Zip;
            loadDetailList.DestinationZipCode = Constant.Zip;
            loadDetailList.LoadId = Guid.Parse("8563c24c-c402-4960-b172-d379543f0096");
            loadDetailList.OriginCityName = Constant.OriginCityName;
            loadDetailList.OriginStateName = Constant.OriginStateName;
            loadDetailList.DestinationCityName = Constant.DestinationCityName;
            loadDetailList.DestinationStateName = Constant.DestinationStateName;
            loadDetailList.OriginLongitude = 34.45666;
            loadDetailList.OriginLatitude = 34.45666;
            loadDetailList.DestinationLongitude = 34.45666;
            loadDetailList.DestinationLatitude = 34.45666;
            loadDetailList.SourceLoadId = 123456;
            var loadDetailMock = new List<LoadDetail>() { loadDetailList }.AsQueryable();
            //this.readContext<IQueryable<LoadDetails>>.Setup(x => x.LoadDetails).Returns(() => loadDetailMock.Object);
            //readContext.Setup(x => x.LoadDetails(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<object[]>())).Returns(tableContent);
            // this.readContext.Setup(x => x.LoadDetails)..Returns(() => loadDetailMock.Object);
            var dbset = new Mock<DbSet<LoadDetail>>();
            dbset.As<IQueryable<LoadDetail>>().Setup(x => x.Provider).Returns(loadDetailMock.Provider);
            dbset.As<IQueryable<LoadDetail>>().Setup(x => x.Expression).Returns(loadDetailMock.Expression);
            dbset.As<IQueryable<LoadDetail>>().Setup(x => x.ElementType).Returns(loadDetailMock.ElementType);
            dbset.As<IQueryable<LoadDetail>>().Setup(x => x.GetEnumerator()).Returns(loadDetailMock.GetEnumerator());
            this.readContext.Setup(x => x.)

            var originCoordinate = new List<LocationCoordinates>() { new LocationCoordinates() { Radius = 75, Latitude = "34.45666", Longitude = "34.45666" } };
            var destinationCoordinate = new List<LocationCoordinates>() { new LocationCoordinates() { Radius = 75, Latitude = "34.45666", Longitude = "34.45666" } };
            var searchByRadius = GetSearchByRadiusObject();

            // Act
            var result = searchByRadius.GlobalSearchMobileByLocation(loadDetail, originCoordinate, destinationCoordinate, 75, 75);

            // Assert to be written
        }
```

The exception it throwing  :
Unable to cast object of type 'System.Linq.Expressions.ConstantExpression' to type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryRootExpression'.

At line `loadDetails = _readContext.LoadDetails.FromSqlRaw(rawsql.ToString()).AsNoTracking().AsQueryable();`

Please help me out.

Stack Trace :

```
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CastHelpers.ChkCast_Helper(Void* toTypeHnd, Object obj)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.RelationalQueryableExtensions.GenerateFromSqlQueryRoot(IQueryable source, String sql, Object[] arguments, String memberName)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.RelationalQueryableExtensions.FromSqlRaw[TEntity](DbSet`1 source, String sql, Object[] parameters)
   at NTG.FH.LoadBoard.Service.Common.SearchByRadius.<GlobalSearchMobileByLocation>d__4.MoveNext() in C:\loadboard\src\NTG.FH.LoadBoard.Service\Common\SearchByRadius.cs:line 125
```

Comment: It is really bad idea to Mock `IQueryable`. Use In-Memory provider and write tests over `DbContext`.

Comment: Can you provide me some example maybe some code or link or point me toward any link

Comment: Something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54265210/10646316)

Comment: Hi @SvyatoslavDanyliv , can you give look to the question again. Actually I posted same code twice. Please give it a look again. I forgot to post the function I am writing test case for.

Comment: So, what you are testing? How EF Core maps SQL result, why not just feed you rests with lists? Looks like you have not mocked everything.