# How to solve IQueryable' doesn't implement 'IAsyncQueryProvider issue

Tags: c#, nunit

i'm trying to write a test to test that the method that gets categoryById returns the correct data but i'm getting a System.AggregateException. please does anyone have an idea how to fix this issue? thanks

Test setup:

```
 [SetUp]
public void Setup()
{
    var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
    {
        cfg.AddProfile<MapperInitilizer>();
    });
    _realMapper = new Mapper(config);
    _categories = new Mock<IRepository<Category>>();
    _unitOfWork = new Mock<IUnitOfWork>();
    _unitOfWork.SetupGet(work => work.Categories).Returns(_categories.Object);
    _logger = new Mock<ILogger<CategoryController>>();
    _mapper = new Mock<IMapper>();
    _categoryController = new CategoryController(_logger.Object, _mapper.Object,_unitOfWork.Object);
    category_one = new Category()
    {
        Id = 1,
        CreatedAt = new DateTime(2022, 8,8),
        Description = "music desc",
        Title = "music"
    };
  
    category_two = new Category()
    {
        Id = 2,
        CreatedAt = new DateTime(2022, 9,8),
        Description = "sport desc",
        Title = "sport"
    };
}
```

CategoryTestRepository's Get method

```
public async Task<Category> Get(Expression<Func<Category, bool>> expression, Func<IQueryable<Category>, IIncludableQueryable<Category, object>> include = null)
{
    IQueryable<Category> query = Source.AsQueryable();
    return await query.AsNoTracking().FirstOrDefaultAsync(expression);
}
```

Get categoryById test

```
[Test]
public void GetCategory_InputCategoryId_ReturnCategoryById()
{
    List<Category> categoryList = new List<Category> {category_one, category_two};

    var expectedResult = categoryList[0];
    
    var repo = new CategoryTestRepository(categoryList);
    var unitOfWork = new Mock<IUnitOfWork>();
    unitOfWork.SetupGet(work => work.Categories).Returns(repo);
    var categoryController = new CategoryController(_logger.Object, _realMapper, unitOfWork.Object);
    categoryController.GetCategory(1).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    
    Assert.IsNotEmpty(repo.Source);
    Assert.AreEqual(expectedResult.Id, repo.Get(x => x.Id == 1).Result);
}
```

Error:

```
    System.AggregateException : One or more errors occurred. (The provider for the source 
 'IQueryable' doesn't implement 'IAsyncQueryProvider'. Only provi...
System.AggregateException : One or more errors occurred. (The provider for the source 'IQueryable' doesn't implement 'IAsyncQueryProvider'. Only providers that implement 'IAsyncQueryProvider' can be used for Entity Framework asynchronous operations.)
  ----> System.InvalidOperationException : The provider for the source 'IQueryable' doesn't implement 'IAsyncQueryProvider'. Only providers that implement 'IAsyncQueryProvider' can be used for Entity Framework asynchronous operations.
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.get_Result()
```

Comment: which OR-Mapper are you using?

Comment: am using AutoMapper EntityFramework

Comment: Instead of mocking the db access, consider using an in memory database https://stackoverflow.com/a/54264935/671619. Should make the mocking easier and solves the problem you are having

Comment: With added benefit that you test the queries in the repositories as well.