# Server Side Caching JQuery Autocomplete for a specific search function

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, caching, jquery-autocomplete

I want to use **Server side caching** with **JQuery UI Autocomplete**. MY site is in ASP.NET 4.5 and I use JQuery 1.9.

I created a webservice function as follows:

```
SearchPhones(string phrase, byte type_id)
```

In order to recognize the caching variable I need to save the phrase and type_id into the variable name if I am correct, so I can refer to that caching variable later on when a query with the same phrase and type_id are asked by other clients. Are there any limitations of this approach (variable name length, in terms of number of characters allowed)?

For example: `HttpContextCurrent.Cache["the_search_term-type_id"]`

I also need to take spaces and other characters into account which are not allowed as part of the variable name. I might get it all wrong though. **I can't** use the Attribute cache on top of the function because it doesn't work with Ajax GET requests for some reason.

Result: need to use server side caching for JQuery autocomplete UI using ASP.NET 4.5 Webservices.

Need your help.  Thanks.

Comment: why don't you use http generic handler rather than web service

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take the benefit of http handler
http://osman.it/aspnet/autocomplete-using-jquery-aspnet-c/
here is a wany by which you can use session `IRequiresSessionState`
[How can I use Session variable in an HttpHandler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1240732/how-can-i-use-session-variable-in-an-httphandler)