# retrieving a property from memebrship class in asp.net via jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I am trying to personalize equipment placement maps in google maps by customer. Is there a way to access a property from the membership class(asp.net id?) via jquery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several choices:

1. Access the current user is by writing it to the response. Something like (JavaScript):

   ```
   var userid = '<%=HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name%>';
   ```
2. Make an ajax request to a web method (either to a Page Methods/Web Service or an HTTP Handler) that returns the current user id. Something like

   ```
   $.post("SomeURL/GetUserID",function(data){  });
   ```

Full examples here: http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use http handler and you can get anything from there.
You can use `IRequiresSessionState` to use access session.
More Detail:
[How can I use Session variable in an HttpHandler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1240732/how-can-i-use-session-variable-in-an-httphandler)


Helpful links to call httphandler from jquery

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/203621/Call-HTTPhandler-from-jQuery-Pass-data-and-retriev

[passing parameter to Http Handler from jQuery call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6828089/passing-parameter-to-http-handler-from-jquery-call)